# Netsuite OAuth 2.0 refresh token expire how to get new one without going to consent page again

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, netsuite

I'm integrating Netsuite with PHP using OAuth 2.0 and it is successfully done. By default netsuite access token stay for 60 minutes and refresh token for 7 days. Once accessToken expires I can get the new one using refreshAccessToken.

Till here everything is good, but when refreshAccessToken expires I didn't find any way to get new refreshAccessToken other than authorising the app again.

As per the documentation:

> When the refresh token expires, the token endpoint returns an invalid_grant error. The application must go back to Step One of the OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant flow to restart the process.

But as I'm calling REST api using CRONS so the challenge is how I'll handle consent screen?

I also followed [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_158081944642.html#subsect_158097952725) to pass prompt as **none** but also doesn't work.
[image]

Need your help if there is any way to get the new refreshAccessToken without going to consent page.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Use the [OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_162730264820.html) which is machine-to-machine and does not require any user interaction. The [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant Flow.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_158074210415.html) requires user interaction.

Comment: Thank you @Brian I'll check that and post my update here.

Comment: It helped me @Brian now I can generate the token using machine-to-machine flow. Thank you!

Comment: You create a certificate manually and upload the public part to NetSuite as part of [OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Setup](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_162686838198.html#OAuth-2.0-Client-Credentials-Setup). Then you do the requests for the short lived tokens using the [POST Request to the Token Endpoint and the Access Token Response](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_162755359851.html#Request-to-the-Token-Endpoint-and-the-Access-Token-Response). The certificate can be valid for up to two years.

Comment: Yes, did the same and it's working fine for now!